# How to give image element a "selected" look using Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm using Raphael.js to draw images to canvas. I need to be able to select certain image elements (this I can do) and make them look like they are selected (this is the problem).

Before Raphael.js I used regular Html5 canvas and simple rectangles. It was simple to delete selected rectangle and draw a new one with a different color to that same place.

But now that I'm using images, it's a different story. The image I'm using is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltPRJ.gif). It's a small gif.

So the question(s):

1. Is there a simple way to change color of a Raphael.js image-element programmatically?
2. Can I make an image-element to blink by changing its opacity?

Only requirement is that the selected element must be movable.

Code for drawing image when user clicks on canvas:

```
var NodeImage = RCanvas.image("../vci3/images/valaisin.gif", position.x, position.y, 30, 30);           
NodeImage.toFront();
RSet.push(NodeImage);
NodeImage.node.id = 'lamp';
NodeImage.node.name = name;
NodeImage.click(function() {
    console.log("Clicked on node " + NodeImage.node.name);  
    // Here should be the code that blinks or changes color or does something else
});
```

Is this completely bad idea? Is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3):

i would suggest granting the `image` with an `opacity` of some level, and assign a value of `1` to it upon click:

```js
NodeImage.attr('opacity', 0.6);
// ...
NodeImage.click(function() {
    this.attr('opacity', 1);
});
```

of course, you will probably want to manage the `shape`'s selected state, to switch the selected style off later on. in fact, you'll want to manage all selectable shapes in the same manner, so let's do that:

```js
// keep all selectable shapes in a group to easily manage them
var selectableShapesArray = [NodeImage, otherNodeImage, anotherSelectableShape];

// define the behavior for shape click event
var clickHandler = function() {
    for (var i in selectableShapesArray) {
        var image = selectableShapesArray[i];
        if (image.selected) {
            image.attr('opacity', .6);
            image.selected = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    this.attr('opacity', 1);
    this.selected = true;
}

// attach this behavior as a click handler to each shape
for (var i in selectableShapesArray) {
    var shape = selectableShapesArray[i];
    shape.click(clickHandler);
}​
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

I ended doing something similar. Made a custom function for my nodeimage-element that uses JQuery to animate opacity changes. I use a dictionary to track single elements clicked/selected state, so that I know when to start and stop animations.

I'm not completely happy with this solution because this 'blink' feeling doesn't really jump out from the background..

Comment: it is of courtesy to accept the answer, or up-vote for it, if you have found it correct or useful. thanks.

Comment: BTW, it seems redundant to use jQuery's animation, as you can use the [built in capabilities of Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.animate) for that purpose.